# Saving values to NSArray - (First in Last out)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to assign an array which can have `4` slots. (meaning, the array could only store `4` values in it).

I will be adding more content to this NSArray, and since it can store only `4` records, the record i added last will be removed (`First in Last out`)

For example. i will be storing the values `1,2,3,4`. And when i add the value `5`, the value `1` should be removed and the array should have the following structure `2,3,4,5`.

Then if i add the value `6`, the value `2` will be removed and have the following structure, `3,4,5,6`.

How can i do this progrmatically ? Sorry i am unable to show my workings because i have no clue how to start this.

Comment: Is this not first in first out? The one goes in first and is the first to be taken out...

Answer (score 4):

Make it an `NSMutableArray`, not an `NSArray`. Add an object to the end like so:

```
[myArray addObject:object];
```

Remove the first item:

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
// assume val is a valid integer
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:val]];
if ([array length] > 4)
{
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad:

```
  arrayIndex = o;
```

In addObjectsInArray:

```
  -(void)addObjectsInArray:(NSNumber*)number{
         if(arrayIndex<4){
               [array addObject:number];
               arrayIndex++;
         }
         else{
               [array replaceObjectAtIndex:(arrayIndex%4) withObject:number];
               arrayIndex++;
         }

  }
```